# How to escape backslash in ElasticSerach query

Tags: elasticsearch, backslash

I have the following field in ElasticSearch:

```
 "type": "doc\doc1"
```

My goal is to select a special type, I tried:

```
GET /my_index/my_type/_search
{
"query":{  
  "bool":{  
     "must":{  
        "term":{  
           "type": "doc\\doc1"
        }
     }
  }
}
}
```

but it does not works, I tried:

```
"type": "doc\\\\doc1"
"type": "\"doc\\\\doc1"\"
"type": "\"doc\\doc1"\"
```

but the query returns no results.

I tried with:

```
GET /my_index/my_type/_search
{
"query" : { 
  "query_string" : {
    "query" : "doc\\doc1",
    "analyzer": "keyword"      
  } 
}
}
```

But it's the same output.

Any helps would be greatly appreciated

Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45948547/trouble-escaping-elasticsearch-query/45951476#45951476

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape backslash in your field value.

Then you can search the exact value with the keyword analyzer with term query or instead you can use match query with analyzed value:

```
PUT test
{
   "settings": {
      "number_of_shards": 1
   },
   "mappings": {
      "type1": {
         "properties": {
            "field1": {
               "type": "text",
               "fields": {
                  "raw": {
                     "type": "keyword"
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}


PUT test/type1/1
{
    "field1" : "doc\\doc1"
}


POST test/_search?pretty
{
   "query": {
      "bool": {
         "must": {
            "term": {
               "field1.raw": "doc\\doc1"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}


POST test/_search?pretty
{
   "query": {
      "bool": {
         "must": {
            "match": {
               "field1": "doc\\doc1"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but your field is "field1": "doc\\doc1" and not "field1": "doc\doc1"