# The datetime zone id 'america' is not recognised in Elasticasearch script

Tags: elasticsearch, groovy

I have an Elasticsearch index for hotel locations with timezone details as below

```
{
"location":"1",
.
.
. 
"timezone": {
            "timeZoneName": "Eastern Daylight Time",
            "rawOffset": -18000,
            "timeZoneId": "America/New_York",
            "dstOffset": 3600,
            "status": "OK"
          }
}
```

I'm using this timezone detail in elasticsearch script to filter docs.

```
def current_date = new Date(); 
def loc_date = current_date.setZone(org.joda.time.DateTimeZone.forID(doc['timezone.timeZoneId'].value)); 
def day=loc_date.format('EEEE').toString().toLowerCase();
```

While I'm using timezone details in my elasticsearch script (Groovy) it is throwing below error

```
"type": "script_exception",
          "reason": "failed to run indexed script [uc-time-test38] using lang [groovy]",
          "caused_by": {
            "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
            "reason": "The datetime zone id 'america' is not recognised"
          }
```

Looks like **doc['timezone.timeZoneId'].value** is only returning **america** not **America/New_York**

Tried to convert **doc['timezone.timeZoneId'].value** as String **doc['timezone.timeZoneId'].value.toString()** but problem is still remain same.

My Elasticsearch version is 2.3

Also querying in index is not giving result when search with `America/New_York`

Below query is returning all results

```
   {
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": {
            "term": {
              "timezone.timeZoneId": "america"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

but this giving 0 result

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "term": {
          "timezone.timeZoneId": "America/New_York"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

ES mapping

```
.
.
.
"timezone": {
        "properties": {
          "timeZoneName": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "rawOffset": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "timeZoneId": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "dstOffset": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "status": {
            "type": "string"
          }
        }
      },
.
.
.
```

Comment: OK, so the data you think you have in your doc is not the actual data you have. What is your question?

Comment: Question is why is throwing the error "The datetime zone id 'america' is not recognised" while I have timezone id as "America/New_York"?

Comment: As you saw, you **don't** have timezone id as "America/New_York" in doc['timezone.timeZoneId'].value. What you do have is "america". Maybe you have the right value elsewhere, but not in doc['timezone.timeZoneId'].value.

Comment: I made another index with only 5 records so that I can check manually there is not record with timezone id as 'america'. Same error throwing

Comment: Do the backslash may be an issue in elasticsearch doc? like I'm getting only the first part i.e. "america" of string "America/New_York"  not the full string "America/New_York".

Comment: Pedant alert: that's a _forward_ or common slash, not a backslash. But, yes. You should see how this index is consumed to create the def. I'd stare harder at that date formatting you are doing. There is nothing trivial about formatting any dates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it. Problem was with the saved timezone id. timeZoneId field was analysed thats why assuming string `America/New_York` as two separate keywords, `America` and `New_York`.

What I did

- Backed up old index
- Create a new index with new mapping, Set timeZoneId field as not_analysed (keyword)
- Pushed all data to new index
- Now `doc['timezone.timeZoneId'].value` returns `America/New_York` in script

Hope this can help others. Thanks for discussion.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Grab(group='joda-time', module='joda-time', version='2.9.9')
import org.joda.time.DateTimeZone

//this line prints America/New_York
println DateTimeZone.forID('America/New_York')

//this one throws exception
//java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The datetime zone id 'America' is not recognised
println DateTimeZone.forID('America')
```

so the problem somewhere in your data

Comment: I think problem may be in the storage of timezone id.  Do the backslash may be an issue in elasticsearch doc? like I'm getting only the first part i.e. "america" of string "America/New_York"  not the full string "America/New_York".

Comment: ok, just put a constant `'America/New_York'` instead of `doc['timezone.timeZoneId'].value` and check if it working